# How can I restrict access of ALL OTHER (standard) users to a specific user folder in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions, user-folders

A computer with Windows 10 Pro has several users (let's use administrator A and standard users B and C as examples). In addition to the already existing standard folders (in the /users/), I would like to make further folders that only a specific user has access to, possibly on other drives. I don't mind if the administrator account(s) can have access to those folders. But the other regular users should not have access.

I have found instructions about restricting access by other users (for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1115595/windows-10-how-do-i-lock-limit-another-users-access-to-my-folders)). The advice is to prohibit user B's folder from user C (and possible other **already existing** users). But this approach has at least two major flaws:

1. If you have many users, it's quite **cumbersome** to go through all
   new folders and prohibit all others of using them.  2)
2. If the computer has **a new user** (say, D), the new user will have access to B's and
   C's private folders (unless the administrator who created the account
   remembers to assign the appropriate prohibitions).

So is there a way to define folder permissions in such a way that all other users cannot access the folder **by default**? I'm thinking of setting something in the permissions of the user's folder, not something that affects the folder functions in a more complicated manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable permission inheritance for those folders. Then **remove** the "Users" or "Everyone" access entries, replacing them with just the specific accounts or groups that you need to grant access to. Everyone else will be automatically denied access.

Windows permissions are generally evaluated in this order:

1. If a user matches a "Deny" entry, they're denied the permission.
2. If a user matches an "Allow" entry, they're granted the permission.
3. If a user doesn't match any entries, they're denied the permission.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good, will need to try it. When doing so, I removed the permission and there is a checkbox "Replace all child object permissions entries with inheritable permission entries from this object". What does this mean and should I select it too? What about subfolders of this folder? If the user creates ones, are those automatically also protected, or is it precisely this "child object" checkbox that defines it?

Comment: They're related, but not exactly as you imagine. Permission inheritance is specified individually for each entry, in the "Applies to" column -- if you leave it set to "This folder, subfolders, and files" then that entry will indeed apply to newly created subfolders and files.

Comment: However, just like I told you to disable inheritance for _this_ folder (so that it would no longer receive permissions from its parent, instead allowing them to be directly edited), it is possible that you might have some file or subfolder deep inside that also has its inheritance disabled. It is also possible that you might have some file/subfolder that is inheriting permissions, but _also_ has additional entries granting or denying access.

Comment: So the "Replace" checkbox isn't a permanent setting, instead it performs a one-time cleanup operation -- it forces all items inside this folder to _enable_ inheritance and discard any custom ACLs, ensuring that all of the folder's contents will have consistent permissions inherited from the folder that you're currently editing. It is not strictly needed, as most of the items inside will already be set this way, but it can be used if you want to be 100% sure.

Comment: (And by "one-time" I mean that you _do not_ need to use it every time you edit permissions on the folder. Even without it, inheritable permissions will be automatically carried over to all files and subfolders that have inheritance enabled. The checkbox is just a "reset this mess" feature.)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you very much! Sorry, but one (hopefully last) question: do you see any problems in the solution suggested by @Devanshu Sharma, which seems simpler?

Comment: +1 I agree with the answer posted here and (infrequently) have used these ideas.

Comment: what about "authenticated users"? Do I need to remove it or not?

Comment: what about "authenticated users"? Do I need to remove it or not?

Comment: I suppose you do? "Authenticated users" pretty much means "Everyone" – it grants (or denies) rights to every non-anonymous user.

Comment: So i remove both "users" and "authenticated users" and add my user and I should be able to be the only one accessing that folder?

Answer (score 0):

*This Thing Work in Most of Windows*

## Follow the Following Steps:-

- Firstly open the Folder in Windows Explorer
- Right Click on Folder
- Select Properties
- a New Window appears
- Goto Security tab
- Click on `Edit` Button
- Select Users, it Will be Displayed as (`Computername/Users`)
- Check Full Control in Deny row......
  And you are Done

Comment: Thanks this sounds good too. But it seems to be that there is a bit difference here compared to the answer by @user1686. Are there any different consequences in doing it one way or the other?

Comment: @kissel: The consequences are that a "Deny" overrides all "Allow" entries. If you deny all permissions to the "Users" group, then _nobody_ who's a member of that group will be able to gain access -- even if you try to add "Allow" entries for them individually. (Most admin accounts belong to the "Users" group too, so doing so would deny access to admins as well.)

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I followed @user1686 's answer which is accurate and self explanatory, I would although improvise on steps for novice users below:

1. Right click folder >  `Properties` > `Security` > `Advanced` > `Disable inheritance` > `Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object` > `Apply`.
2. Explicitly add your user that should continue to have access, to this list by clicking `Add` > `Select a principal` > type Username > `Check names` > (ensure it has guessed correct user) > `Ok`. Now ensure `Type` is set to: `Allow` > tick `[ ] Full control` > `Ok`.
3. click on below entries and click `Remove` one by one:

> ```
>     a. Authenticated Users
>     b. Users (your-PC-Name/Users)
> ```

4. tick `[ ] Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries` > `Apply` > `Ok`.