Restrict Folder Access for a "Guest Account" on Windows 11 Home
I occasionally want to let people use my laptop to watch some videos using a different local account. I do not want them to have access to a variety of folders. This is Windows 11 Home, which I understand does have limitations.
Is there a way to restrict folder access by user account, or do I need to upgrade to the Pro version?

Which folders are you trying to restrict – system folders like C:\Windows, or the standard C:\Users folders, or custom folders?

See https://superuser.com/questions/1631716/how-can-i-restrict-access-of-all-other-standard-users-to-a-specific-user-folde for a Win 10 answer. Also, if it is data you want restricted, you might encrypt just specific folders, e.g., <user>\Document, \Pictures, etc., with a utility such as VeraCrypt.
